# Is there a way to have a user set a password that is against a list of bad pws on AD?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, password

I only see server 2008 have a password requirement users must have. But is there a way to also have the password searched against a list of bad passwords to force a user have a list that meets the pw requirement but also not have a password that is on the list?

Comment: This may be worth a read - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770842(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Nice topic, this one could help u too. https://blog.netwrix.com/2016/03/03/how-to-set-up-multiple-password-and-account-lockout-policies/